# How to fetch into multiple classes?

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

Let's say I have 3 tables that are related. How can I query all 3 inner joined and get the result in 3 different record types for each table?

e.g. something like:

```
dslContext
.select(A.fields()).from(B).innerJoin(A).on(...)
.fetchInto(A,B) ???
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want something like `Record3<ARecord, BRecord, CRecord>`, you can simply [nest the projeced records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-clause/select-clause-table/):

```java
Result<Record3<ARecord, BRecord, CRecord>> result =
ctx.select(A, B, C) // Project the tables directly, not their fields
   .from(A)
   .join(B).on(...)
   .join(C).on(...)
   .fetch();
```